# How to pass parameters in stat_function() ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, distribution

Lets say I have the following code:

```
get_histogram <- function(data_set, column_name, bin_width, attribute_name) {
  ggplot(data_set, aes(x= {{column_name}})) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y= ..density..), binwidth = .3, fill= "lightblue", colour="black") +
    xlab(paste0(attribute_name)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm , args= list(mean= mean({{column_name}}), sd= sd({{column_name}})), 
                  mapping = aes(colour = "Normal"))+
    stat_function(fun = dlnorm, args = list(meanlog= mean(log({{column_name}})), sdlog= sd(log({{column_name}}))),
                  mapping = aes(colour = "LogNormal")) + 
    scale_colour_manual("Distribution", values = c("red", "blue"))
}

data <- rnorm(1000, 44, 2)
df <- data.frame(data)
get_histogram(df, data, 1, "Test")
```

This works fine, right? So, we know the code is correct.

Now, the problem arises when I run the same code on a dataset that I cannot share here. When I run the first chunk of the code on it, the code works perfectly. I mean when I execute the following part:

```
get_histogram_chucnk <- function(data_set, column_name, bin_width, attribute_name) {
  ggplot(data_set, aes(x= {{column_name}})) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y= ..density..), binwidth = .3, fill= "lightblue", colour="black") +
    xlab(paste0(attribute_name)) 
}
get_histogram_chunk(new_df, columnX , 1, "Test")
```

As you can see here, I am passing new_df and columnX, which are coming from my real dataset (as I mentioned earlier, unfortunately, I cannot share my data). Once again, this chunk of code works just fine. However, when I run the entire code, I encounter the error **'object 'columnX' not found.'** While debugging, I found that the error occurs in the following line...

```
stat_function(fun = dnorm , args= list(mean= mean({{column_name}}), sd= sd({{column_name}}))
```

The issue is occurring with the {{column}} name.
I have checked everything and the fact that this code runs fine on the first chunk of code makes me confident that the issue is not with the dataset, but rather with the **stat_function()**.

This code also works fine when I plot the graph outside of a function and pass the column name and data frame as hardcoded values. Therefore, I am sure that stat_function() doesn't like how I'm passing the column name. However, if that is indeed the case, why does it work with the sample data?

I understand that it's difficult to provide a precise answer without actual data, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
PS the minimum value of columnX is 50 so the logNorm should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the places where you use something like `mean({{column_name}})` to something like `mean(data_set[[colname]])` and use `colname = as_label(enquo(column_name))` at the beginning of the code, it should work.  Also, note `..density..` has been replaced with `after_stat(density)`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
get_histogram <- function(data_set, column_name, bin_width, attribute_name) {
  require(rlang)
  colname <- as_label(enquo(column_name))
  ggplot(data_set, aes(x= {{ column_name }})) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y= after_stat(density)), binwidth = .3, fill= "lightblue", colour="black") +
    xlab(paste0(attribute_name)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm , args= list(mean= mean(data_set[[colname]]), sd= sd(data_set[[colname]])), 
                  mapping = aes(colour = "Normal"))+
    stat_function(fun = dlnorm, args = list(meanlog= mean(log(data_set[[colname]])), sdlog= sd(log(data_set[[colname]]))),
                  mapping = aes(colour = "LogNormal")) + 
    scale_colour_manual("Distribution", values = c("red", "blue"))
}

data <- rnorm(1000, 44, 2)
df <- data.frame(data)
get_histogram(df, data, 1, "Test")
#> Loading required package: rlang
```

[image]

```r
get_histogram(mtcars, mpg, 1, "MPG")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my life :) I have been trying to solve this for a couple of days I literally got headache. You are my today hero!

Comment: As a learning opportunity, I am wondering if you know why the initial code worked for the sample data?

Comment: It worked at first because you make an object called `data` in your workspace and then make a data frame called `df` from data.  So, when you call `mean({{column_name}}` it's actually doing `mean(data)` which is grabbing the `data` object from your workspace rather than `mean(df$data)` which is what you intended.  If, after you do `df <- data.frame(data)` you then remove `data` with `rm(data)`, you should see that the code that did work no longer works.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: was there a reason why that in  **ggplot(data_set, aes(x= {{ column_name }}))** you still passed column_name in double curly bracket instead of **data_set[[colname]]**. In other words, do we only use **data_set[[colname]]** for occasions that we want do some calculations?

Comment: The `{{column_name}}` works in `aes()` because `aes()` expects symbols and looks to retrieve the data based on the symbol from the dataset.  Things outside of the `aes()` don't look in the data for variables, so something like `mean({{column_name}})` will not work because `stat_fun()` doesn't know to look in the inherited data for the appropriate column.